# Want to show zoom in zoom out on map through buttons in ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, uibutton, zooming

I want to add buttons on map in ios sdk Mapview
1> Zoom in button
2> Zoom out button
Please specify any demo or any code related to this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for zoom in

```
-(void)zoomInMap
{
region.span.latitudeDelta = region.span.latitudeDelta/2 ;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = region.span.longitudeDelta/2;



    region.center.latitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude ;
    region.center.longitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude ;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

similarly for zoom out.